# Image onLoad callback being called before image fully rendered in React

Tags: javascript, css, image, reactjs, onload

I'm trying to do something pretty basic with react. I have a src URL for my image, which is a very large image (9999x9999 ~ 2.5mb).

I'm rendering a Loading component and the image (with the src). The image has a visibility: hidden style on it.

When the onLoad is called on the image, I'm updating a var in state, which will hide the loading component, and change the visibility of the image.

This all works as expected, however the onload seems to be called about 1/1.5 seconds before the image displays. I see the loading spinner which briefly spins, but this then freezes along with the whole application for those 1/1.5 seconds, before the loader disappears correctly and the image renders? When I update state, check 'completed' on the image, it rerenders the app. I then get the freeze.

You can kind of see the behaviour here: [GIF](https://imgflip.com/gif/1zd78a)

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Loading from '../../../components/Loading';

function generateSizeStyle(size) {
  if (!size) { return {}; }

  return { width: size, height: size };
}

function getHiddenStyle({ imageLoaded }) {
  return imageLoaded ? void 0 : { visibility: 'hidden' };
}

export default class Image extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      imageLoaded: false
    };

    this.setImageLoaded = this.setImageLoaded.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.data !== this.props.data || nextProps.path !== this.props.path) {
      this.setState({ imageLoaded: false });
    }
  }

  getImageStyle() {
    const { size } = this.props;
    const { imageLoaded } = this.state;

    return { ...generateSizeStyle(size), ...getHiddenStyle({ imageLoaded }) };
  }

  setImageLoaded() {
    this.setState({ imageLoaded: true });
    console.log(document.getElementById('img'));
  }

  render() {
    const { data, alt, imageType, path } = this.props;

    if (!data && !path) { return null; }

    const { imageLoaded } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={`image ${imageType}`}>
        {!imageLoaded ? <Loading /> : null}
        <img
          id="img"
          onLoad={this.setImageLoaded}
          src={data || path}
          alt={alt}
          style={this.getImageStyle()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Image.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.string,
  alt: PropTypes.string,
  size: PropTypes.number,
  path: PropTypes.string,
  imageType: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

Image.defaultProps = {
  data: void 0,
  alt: '',
  size: void 0,
  path: void 0
};
```

Any ideas?

Regards,
Alex